# SyntaxError: /home/container/config.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 2769

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

Im getting this SyntaxError: /home/container/config.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 2769 error,

here's my config.json

```
   "discordGuildId":"775307362915450900",
   "hypixelGuildId":"60a690798ea8c9bb7f6d9b30",
   "colours":{
      "main":"00FFF0",
      "secondary":"202225",
      "success":"00FF50",
      "warning":"FFFF10",
      "error":"FF1F00"
   },
   "roles":{
      "guildMemberRole":"955388286539558932",
      "helpers":[
         "890624191508926505",
         "959322231735996426"
      ],
      "adminRole":[
         "847067680791986208",
         "890624191508926505"
      ]
   },
   "scheduledEvents":{
      "leaderboardDataUpdate":"*/1 * */1 * *"
   },
   "channels":{
      "logChannelId":"987630136767705158",
      "appChannelId":"987630136767705158",
      "queueChannelId":"841940876077826048",
      "ticketCategoryId":"955423323095961710",
      "starboardChannelId":"955423323095961710",
      "memberCount":{
         "discord":"960082737249796096",
         "guild":"960082737249796096"
      }
   },
   "emoji":{
      "warning":"<:warning_emoji:868054485992357948>",
      "error":"<:error_emoji:868054485946224680>",
      "star":"<:GoldStar:905915895937892403>",
      "log":"<:log_emoji:868054485933625346>",
      "helpEmoji":"<:KannaSip:889543061821063189>",
      "helpCommands":"<:slash:913172347639435285>",
      "helpButtons":"<:button:913172562001928193>",
      "helpMenus":"<:dropdown_select:914106174754947113>",
      "github":"<:github:888155742719328276>",
      "plus":"<:plus:888072519582634075>",
      "minus":"<:minus:888072653003452516>"
   },
   "selectMenus":[
      {
         "name":"UNIQUE_STRING",
         "description":"STRING",
         "placeholder":"STRING",
         "disabled":true,
         "maxValues":"INTEGER",
         "minValues":"INTEGER",
         "options":[
            {
               "value":"UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_1",
               "label":"STRING",
               "description":"STRING",
               "emoji":"EMOJI"
            },
            {
               "value":"UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_2",
               "label":"STRING",
               "description":"STRING",
               "emoji":"EMOJI"
            },
            {
               "value":"UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_3",
               "label":"STRING",
               "description":"STRING",
               "emoji":"EMOJI"
            },
            "..."
         ],
         "actions":{
            "UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_1":{
               "actionType":"toggleRole",
               "roleID":"DISCORDID"
            },
            "UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_2":{
               "actionType":"removeRole",
               "roleID":"DISCORDID"
            },
            "UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_3":{
               "actionType":"addRole",
               "roleID":"DISCORDID"
            },
            "..."
         }, // error seems to be from like right here
      },
      "..."
   ],
   "chatbridge":{
      "enabled":true,
      "channelId":"987630984541376533",
      "webhook":"censored",
      "messagelogging":{
         "enabled":false,
         "channelId":"DISCORDID"
      },
      "relogOnKick":{
         "enabled":false,
         "relogAmount":1
      },
      "serverJoinLeaveMessages":{
         "enabled":true
      },
      "guildJoinLeaveMessages":{
         "enabled":false,
         "logging":false
      },
      "autoInviteOnApp":true
   },
   "url":{
      "guild_staff_application":"URL",
      "forums_post":"censored"
   },
   "guildAppReqs":{
      "textReqs":[
         150m nw,
         650 weight
      ],
      "minNetworkLevel":1
   },
   "starboard":{
      "minimumCount":1
   }
}
```

Can someone please help me fix this I am pretty sure I am supposed to add a : but i dont know how to fix this syntax error I dont understand what is wrong,

using node v16

Comment: Dangling commas are invalid in JSON. As is `"textReqs":[ 150m nw, 650 weight ],`  I suggest you validate and clean up the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any online JSON validator, like [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com). It's output for your JSON:
[image]

So here is the fixed one:

```
{
 "discordGuildId":"775307362915450900",
   "hypixelGuildId":"60a690798ea8c9bb7f6d9b30",
   "colours":{
      "main":"00FFF0",
      "secondary":"202225",
      "success":"00FF50",
      "warning":"FFFF10",
      "error":"FF1F00"
   },
   "roles":{
      "guildMemberRole":"955388286539558932",
      "helpers":[
         "890624191508926505",
         "959322231735996426"
      ],
      "adminRole":[
         "847067680791986208",
         "890624191508926505"
      ]
   },
   "scheduledEvents":{
      "leaderboardDataUpdate":"*/1 * */1 * *"
   },
   "channels":{
      "logChannelId":"987630136767705158",
      "appChannelId":"987630136767705158",
      "queueChannelId":"841940876077826048",
      "ticketCategoryId":"955423323095961710",
      "starboardChannelId":"955423323095961710",
      "memberCount":{
         "discord":"960082737249796096",
         "guild":"960082737249796096"
      }
   },
   "emoji":{
      "warning":"<:warning_emoji:868054485992357948>",
      "error":"<:error_emoji:868054485946224680>",
      "star":"<:GoldStar:905915895937892403>",
      "log":"<:log_emoji:868054485933625346>",
      "helpEmoji":"<:KannaSip:889543061821063189>",
      "helpCommands":"<:slash:913172347639435285>",
      "helpButtons":"<:button:913172562001928193>",
      "helpMenus":"<:dropdown_select:914106174754947113>",
      "github":"<:github:888155742719328276>",
      "plus":"<:plus:888072519582634075>",
      "minus":"<:minus:888072653003452516>"
   },
   "selectMenus":[
      {
         "name":"UNIQUE_STRING",
         "description":"STRING",
         "placeholder":"STRING",
         "disabled":true,
         "maxValues":"INTEGER",
         "minValues":"INTEGER",
         "options":[
            {
               "value":"UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_1",
               "label":"STRING",
               "description":"STRING",
               "emoji":"EMOJI"
            },
            {
               "value":"UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_2",
               "label":"STRING",
               "description":"STRING",
               "emoji":"EMOJI"
            },
            {
               "value":"UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_3",
               "label":"STRING",
               "description":"STRING",
               "emoji":"EMOJI"
            },
            "..."
         ],
         "actions":{
            "UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_1":{
               "actionType":"toggleRole",
               "roleID":"DISCORDID"
            },
            "UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_2":{
               "actionType":"removeRole",
               "roleID":"DISCORDID"
            },
            "UNIQUE_STRING-example_name_3":{
               "actionType":"addRole",
               "roleID":"DISCORDID"
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "chatbridge":{
      "enabled":true,
      "channelId":"987630984541376533",
      "webhook":"censored",
      "messagelogging":{
         "enabled":false,
         "channelId":"DISCORDID"
      },
      "relogOnKick":{
         "enabled":false,
         "relogAmount":1
      },
      "serverJoinLeaveMessages":{
         "enabled":true
      },
      "guildJoinLeaveMessages":{
         "enabled":false,
         "logging":false
      },
      "autoInviteOnApp":true
   },
   "url":{
      "guild_staff_application":"URL",
      "forums_post":"censored"
   },
   "guildAppReqs":{
      "textReqs":[
         '150m nw',
         '650 weight'
      ],
      "minNetworkLevel":1
   },
   "starboard":{
      "minimumCount":1
   }
}
```